# PDO query construction with GROUP BY , ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble using `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` , `LIMIT`, in general my queries work fine however when I try to get more specific I keep running into problems. I try to break it down and go step by step but I can't figure out issue.

From my **User Class** I call DB like this:

```
$this->_db->get('listings', array('userid', '=', $this->data()->id, ' AND ',
'email', ' = ', $this->data()->email, ' GROUP BY reference ORDER BY row ASC'));
```

My **DB** Class is set up like this:

```
public function get($table, $where){return $this->action('SELECT * ', $table, $where);}


private function action($action, $table, $where = array()){
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=' , 'AND' ,'OR', 'LIKE', 'GROUP BY','ORDER BY', 'ASC', 'DESC');

        if(!empty($where)){
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE ";
            if(count($where) > 3){
                $sql .= "(";
                $isOp = FALSE;
                foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
                    if($isOp){ 
                        if(in_array($value, $operators)){
                            $sql .= " {$value} ";
                            $isOp = FALSE;
                        }else{return FALSE;}
                    }else{
                        $sql .= " {$value} ";
                        $isOp = TRUE;
                    }
                }
                $sql .= ")";

                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){return $this;}
            }else if(count($where) === 3){
                $field      = $where[0]; 
                $operator   = $where[1];
                $value      = $where[2];
                if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
                    $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?"; // NO $value ?
                    if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){return $this;}
                }
            }
        }else{
            // If array is empty
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table}";
            if(!$this->query($sql)->error()){return $this;}
        }
        return FALSE;
    }


public function query($sql, $params = array()){
        $this->_error = FALSE;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)){
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }// End IF count

            if($this->_query->execute()){
                    $this->_lastID = $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
                    try{
                        $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    }catch(Exception $e){
                        // Catch Error
                    }
                    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            }else{$this->_error = TRUE;}
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

In general I am building everything from scratch by reading tutorials and following instructions from books.

Again I am having trouble with the following Group By, Order By, Like, Limit.. I am probably not binding it correctly however I don't have enough knowledge to find my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

**ERROR I GET**

> SELECT * FROM listings WHERE ( userid = 4 GROUP BY reference )exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY reference )' at line 1

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: @Uueerdo that is not my issue, I have problem with binding the values correctly.  I believe my issue lies inside the function query()

Comment: The error you supplied indicates otherwise, `GROUP BY` is not a valid condition for a WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of de ( ) in you code (DB class):

```
$sql .= "(";
$sql .= ")";
```

The GROUP BY should not be in the () section of the WHERE.

WHERE ( userid = 4 GROUP BY reference )

Must be:

```
WHERE ( userid = 4 ) GROUP BY reference;
```

Or better:

```
WHERE userid = 4 GROUP BY reference;
```

You use the GROUP BY function when you use SUM, COUNT, etc. in the SELECT. Else you don't need it.